# VS2005 setup Launch Condition for Windows Server OS

Tags: visual-studio, windows-installer

I have a VS2005 setup project. I want to put a launch condition for the MSI such that it is installable  only on Windows Server OS's. Installation must fail for other Windows OS.
What condition can I use?

Thanks,
Kunal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MsiNTProductType property value has a value greater than one for servers:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370329(v=vs.85).aspx

so you can use that in your launch condition, >1

Comment: My personal preference is to identify what the actual dependency is and gate on that instead.  It's a nicer experience for the user.